# How do I set up a scope to eager load an association with a condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I have a join-model "UserPermission" that relates to "User", "Shop" and "Permission".

I'd like to be able to eager-load all the instances of Permission with a scope called on the User model based on a Shop's id.

The scope created would look like this:

```
User.for_shop(1)
```

This would issue one query for the user, and then a followup query to Permission that joins against UserPermission where `shop_id == 1`

Comment: Can you please mention your models in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
scope :for_shop, lambda { |shop_id| where(:shop_id => shop_id).includes(:permissions) }
```

You have another (equivalent) option:

```
Shop.find(1).users.includes(:permissions)
```

Either way you get a scoped list of users. Their permissions are eager loaded, so when you do something like:

```
user = User.for_shop(1).first
user.permissions
```

The second line won't hit the database; that user's permissions have been eager loaded in the previous line.